# Alien/Unknown Network computer/device/pc (Windows 7)

Tags: networking

I have a problem with my sisters network.

She have 3 computers (Windows 7), she's using a switch, i guess that's a good reason why all 3 of them does appear under Networks.

But there also appears another unknown computer and media devices periodically and i am unaware why, how, where from.

I disconnected her other computers, definitely it's not one of them.

[image]

[image]

But "EGILS-PC" and "EGILS" devices are our mystery, they show up periodically, and she kind of don't have a wi-fi. In screens you can see another device "EW7206APG", a router which one she doesn't have, but an antenna on the roof and internet connection via radio. :O

I found that routers IP and can open it in browser, but don't have an access

All we know, she have an antenna, and behind that there is some mysterious router and "EGILS" devices.

How could this "router" could be connected with antenna? Where does those "EGILS" devices came from? Could be that a neighbor is doing some tricks?

Comment: Your sister does not have a switch but a wireless router and somebody is connected to it.  Furthermore disable network discovery to off.

Comment: Add a password to the wireless router for your sister. This *may* help in kicking the leecher off. Also if it is extremely troublesome to her, and she is ONLY wired turn off the wireless radio in the router firmware.

Comment: She does not have a router, that's for sure.

Comment: She does not have a router, that's for sure. But i am not informed how this internet via radio works... could be possible that ISP has been setted up just a router with amplifier on the roof?  That's all i know, there is an antenna and some kind of box up there that is connected to power grid.

Answer (score 0):

Just go to your router/modem page change the local network IP

Like if your ISP provided you 192.168.0.1; x=can be any number from (3 to 254) instead 0.1.2 they are common in public networks comment problem of showing up the system.

Restart all your hardware like router modem or PC on same network or home.

All the Alien/Unknown Network computer/device/pc will go away.

It’s because of protocol over WAN that can be used for file printer sharing.